# Woo Commerce Custom Attribute/Field in Order Panel and E-mail

Tags: php, customization, woocommerce, woothemes

I would like to set up a custom attribute or field for my products that will show up in the order panel and new order e-mail for the admin. These would be fields such as the source and product cost and would not be visible to the shopper. I'm not sure which would be more appropriate to set them as custom field or attributes and how to have them display on the admin's order page and new order e-mail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can achieve this using the answers in the below links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440471/woocommerce-orders-page-add-customer-role-custom-column
&
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507977/how-to-change-senders-email-in-woocommerce