# WooCommerce orders page add customer role custom column

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add column to show the customer role on the WooCommerce orders, I search and everything I found is for one user. I also found this code on this link ([WooCommerce show custom column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683162/woocommerce-show-custom-column/16595054#16595054)) but I do not understand where I put what I need.
I also found this code (https://gist.github.com/corsonr/5975207)
but I do not managed to get the user role.
I added `$user_role = $user->roles;` 
and

```
switch ($column)
    {
        case "user_role":
            echo $user_role;
        break;  

    }
```

but it not worked, I know it is array but use of [0] or [1] did not work.

I missing something?
It is possible to do what I what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below code in your theme functions.php

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_column_heading', 20, 1);

function add_column_heading($array) {


    $res = array_slice($array, 0, 2, true) +
            array("customer_role" => "Customer Role") +
            array_slice($array, 2, count($array) - 1, true);

    return $res;
}

add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_column_data', 20, 2);

function add_column_data($column_key, $order_id) {

    // exit early if this is not the column we want
    if ('customer_role' != $column_key) {
        return;
    }

    $customer = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if($customer->user_id != ''){
            $user = new WP_User( $customer->user_id );
             if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
            foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
               echo $role;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Do you know if it possible to add filtering by user role like the filtering by date? 
(do I better start new topic for this?)