# How to display customer role column in woocommerce order list?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The older way to access customer meta data is not working anymore and I have used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/30452021/2707495 but it doesn't work correctly anymore and gives errors about

> PHP Notice:  user_id was called **incorrectly**. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: WP_List_Table->display, WP_List_Table->display_rows_or_placeholder, WP_Posts_List_Table->display_rows, WP_Posts_List_Table->_display_rows, WP_Posts_List_Table->single_row, WP_List_Table->single_row_columns, WP_Posts_List_Table->column_default, do_action('manage_posts_custom_column'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, add_column_data, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong

Comment: Please show your code and the full error message. Include the line where the PHP Notice is triggered and point to the corresponding line in your code.

Comment: That's all the information is available. The code is one I linked and the error in the log is exactly what I have entered above.