# WordPress/WooCommerce sending mail wrong sender

Tags: php, wordpress, email

So, i've been busy for a client of mine, just on little thing.

His website, build with Wordpress, using WooCommerce has one little problem, i can't fix on my own.

Here's the deal:

When someone places an order, the sender of the automatic mail is: info@xxx.nl

**But**

When someone is not logged in as a registered user, and then clicks the link for password recovery mail. The sender of the automatic mail is completely different from all the other mails.

Even when i'm logged in as a different user, then go to my account and change my password, the confirmation is send from the **right** sender: info@xxx.nl

I've tried all plugins, wordpress hooks, functions.php, nothing seems to work. It's only that little password reset mail.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: By the way, i allready checked wp_user tables, the sender used by the password reset email is no where to be found..

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't solves the issue, please show what `wordpress hooks, functions.php` you used.

Comment: Why are you marking this as answered. the question is completly different....................

Comment: You're not showing your code, you just mention "I tried it all" but without seeing what you tried, it's an off-topic question. By the way, did you try the solution over there?

Comment: I did, nothing works, and if you read the text firmly, you'll understand that ALL EMAILS except the one, with a password recovery link in it, are working. So something is not good.

Comment: and by all i mean:

plugins which are claming to change the sender
wordpress hooks, on every topic, on this website, in the same question-category.

Comment: It's either a programming question here for SO or a support request for the plugin author. There's no other solution, the only hooks for `wp_mail()` function are those ones. Try to disable all plugins and switching theme.

Comment: So please unmark this issue, because no topic on this forum fixed my issue

Comment: Check WP source code for yourself, *there's no other hook* to apply: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ Some other plugin or some code on your theme is causing the bug.

Comment: So, i've found the problem. Its in pluggable.php line 342 & 352.

i changed from mail & from name hardcoded, i don't know how to create a hook, or something like that. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Just put this code on your theme `functions.php` file and you're good to go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43751892/1287812 . .. ... those are the exact hooks for the lines you're hardcoding